# How do I disable the notification "X has left the conversation"

Tags: empathy

When I close the active conversation window, my contact receives a notification that I 
"left the conversation". Is there a setting that prevents displaying this message?

Answer (score 2):

I tried searching Google, but the only thing I was able to find was a couple of other people asking this question with no answer.

I also tried searching the empathy docs, but was unable to find anything.

My hunch is that empathy does not have this feature.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I am going to leave this question unanswered in the hope that someone out there has an answer.